# discord.py : client.wait_for does not detect reaction or messages

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I am writing a bot that is organizing tournaments on *Discord* for a specific game, based on *Discord* ids. I am using the `client.wait_for` to wait for a *thumbs-up* reaction but it seems to go on without stopping even though it got multiple reactions matching the description. There are no errors, it just simply doesn't do anything. Here is the code:

**!** Client is on a different file named `private`.

```
def check(reaction, user):
    return(str(reaction.emoji) == '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}')
try:
    user = await private.client.wait_for('reaction_add', check=check,  timeout = 60.0 )
except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    print("exception caught")
    return
else:
    ...
```

Comment: Your answer has some formatting problems. Try to improve that. Use `\`` brackets for paths and code fragments.

Comment: There aren't any issues with that, that is the code fragment, I used the ... to let you know that there is something there, but it never gets to that point. And that is the whole code fragment that has the issues.

Comment: That's not what I'm talking about, check edits.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I made the suggested adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure THUMBS UP SIGN is the correct emoji? Below is a code example of how waiting for reactions to be added in Discord.py.

```
@client.command()
async def reactcheck(ctx):
    xyz = True
    if xyz == True:
        await ctx.send('Send me that  reaction, mate')

        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''

        try:
            await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=10.0, check=check)
            await ctx.send('')
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send('')
```

Comment: I tried both ways, with that as well. I also have this above the wait_for :
```
await message.add_reaction ( '\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}')
```
And that works perfectly

Comment: so it worked? Or are you getting any errors at least.

Comment: That's the actual problem, the bot knows how to add the thumbs up reaction, but when I do the wait_for it won't identify when other users react to that message, it will just keep waiting and do nothing. He recognizes that THUMBS UP SIGN but it doesnt work in the wait_for function.

Comment: does it identify if the author reacts to the message? Or does it not identify any user, even the author.

Comment: It doesn't identify any user, not even the author